# How to count with 0

Tags: php, count, for-loop

I want to count with 0. I means if

$x = 002
$y = 999

Now I want to count it by keep the 00.

```
for ( $i = $x ; $i <= $y; $i++ )
{
   echo $i;
}
```

but it echo - 002, 3, 4, 5

I want it to count by keep the 00. as like 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012.

Comment: You must be careful when you add leading zeros to your variables. O at the beginning makes PHP use the value as a octal number. It doesn't make any difference for 00-07 but you may get unexpected results for other values. So you should initialize your `$x` simply as `2`, and add leading zeros when you will be printing the output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
for ($i = $x ; $i <= $y; $i++)
{
    printf('%03d', $i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it may make error cause the length of $x is dynamic. 
Though I fixed it with

    $size = strlen ($x);
    for ($i = $x ; $i <= $y; $i++)
    {
        printf ( '%0'.$size.'d', $i );
    }

But is it the right way to do this? I thought I need nested loop to make it work.
But Working well. And thank you.

Comment: Yes, what you described with dynamic size is ok as well.

Comment: The `$i`, `$x` and `$y` in the loop should be normal numbers (1, 2, ...) not zero-padded (001, 002, ...). Though they get converted to regular numbers after the first iteration anyway.

Answer (score 5):

[(s)printf](http://uk.php.net/sprintf) is your friend for this one, there's plenty of useful examples on the manual-page, but you'd want:

`printf('%03d', $i);`

Answer (score 5):

The idea is you don't count it like that, you just show it like that. I hope you understand that 00 is just for presentation only. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

use printf:

```
for ( $i = $x ; $i <= $y; $i++ ) {
    printf("%03d", $i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
   printf('%03d', $i)
```

and link to the [manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

cheers

Answer (score 3):

printf("%03d", $i);

Answer (score 1):

Try using number formats

Refer to here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Just scroll through the bottom.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

[str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad) method:

```
echo str_pad($i, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot do that if $i is an integer. The first time you assign $i it is stored as a string, after you do $i++ its converted to an integer.

If you must maintain the original format, treat $i as a string and do all arithmetic on $i using custom functions, not the build in integer arithmetic.

The easiest solution is to let $i be an integer and prepend leading zeros when you output $i.