# zerofill a integer php

Tags: php, integer, fill, zero, autofill

How would I go about 'zero filling' an integer?

ie

```
1 becomes 0001
40 becomes 0040
174 becomes 0174
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431240/how-to-count-with-0

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
$filled_int = sprintf("%04d", $your_int)
```

Comment: If you want to Zero Pad for 15 digits, should be  like this: 

$filled_int = sprintf("%015d", $your_int)

Answer (score 25):

```
$number = 12;
$width = 4;
$padded = str_pad((string)$number, $width, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: This pads to the right of the number, and pads with spaces not zeros. $padded = str_pad($number, $width, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

Comment: Yeah, ommission on my part. Corrected. But I would retain some semblance of type safety by providing appropriate types (even if conversion is automatic).

Comment: Depending on the scenario, I'd say this is usually the better solution. Additionally, it is not currently necessary to explicitly cast to `string` unless you use a numeric literal in `str_pad`. A variable of a numeric type will be implicitly cast.